# JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this); to render the results of a function in the JSON

Tags: c#, json

Is there any way to get `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` to render the results of a function in the Class?

```
     public string Name { get; private set; } // renders fine in the outputted json



        public string AdHocRecipientsStub()// I want this also in the outputted json
            {
                return AdHocRecipients.ToString().Substring(0, 15) + "...";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap it in a property:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test()));
}

public class Test
{
    public string Test1 { get { return "test1"; } }
    public string Test2 { get { return Test2Func(); } }
    private string Test2Func()
    {
        return "test2";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
{"Test1":"test1","Test2":"test2"}
```